# which is more common US? most people or much people

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, idiomatic-language

For example I have this two vocabulary but which is more common say?

- **Most** people are very bad with me – why, I don't know?
- **Much** people are very bad with me – why, I don't know?

Comment: _Much people_ is ungrammatical, use _many people_.

Comment: maybe this way = many people are very bad with me why, I don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can count X, and there is a lot of X, you have to say *many X*, not *much X*.  If you are using the plural of a noun, it's countable.

*Most X* works whether you can count X or not.

> There are many people in the room.
>
> Most people are in the room.
>
> There is much water in the room.
>
> Most water is in the room.

Comment: One footnote: technically speaking, _most_ only works if we are referring to more than half the people. If 40% of the people are mean, then that's _many_ people being mean. If 60% of the people are mean, then we can say it's _most_ of the people being mean.